# Error installing Duplicator backup on Windows 10 using wampserver

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows, wampserver

I am trying to set up a Wordpress development site on a localhost on Windows 10.  I have tried 32 and 64 bit versions of wampserver but I get the same error when I try to install the Duplicator plugin archive of my active site on Windows 10 when trying to connect to the database.

**Text as follows:**

```
Host:   Fail
Database:   Fail
Version:    no connection
Compatibility:  This Server: [no connection] -- Package Server: [5.6.32]
NOTICE: The current version detected was released prior to MySQL 5.5.3 which had a release date of April 8th 2010. WordPress 4.2 included support for utf8mb4 which is only supported in MySQL server 5.5.3+. It is highly recommended to upgrade your version of MySQL server on this server to be more compatible with recent releases of WordPress and avoid issues with install errors.
```

My Wampserver is running MySql 5.7.21 so this error message can't be correct.

I can run the same archive install on a Mac using MAMP to set up a localhost and it installs correctly so that eliminates a possible corrupt archive error.

I am running Windows 10 pro 17134.81 64 bit.

I've been struggling with this issue for days and have yet to find a solution.

Comment: It sounds like you have another MySQL Server running on your system. This other version is probably getting started automatically and therefore WAMPServers MYSQL can never start as port 3306 has already been grabbed by the other MYSQL

Comment: I suggest uninstalling the old MySQL **but make sure you backup any of YOUR databases first**

Comment: To check look at the running services `services.msc` WAMPServers MySQL is called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64`. If you have another MySQL Server running its service name is probably `MYSQL`

Comment: Only services that are running are the xmappserver MySql, Apache and Maria DB.  No other sql.

Comment: Are you running WAMPServer or XAMPP??

Comment: WAMPServer.  Tried XAMPP and got the same error.